# Infinite loop when using disabled attribute binding to a function

Tags: asp.net-core, angular2-directives, angular-universal

The pre rendering is not working when I bind the "disabled" directive to a function which contains a **console.log()**.

```
<button [disabled]="!isValid()"></button>
```

My function

```
 public isValid(){
     console.log("isvalid");
     return true;
 }
```

From my visual studio output console, I got this :

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Information: isvalid
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Information: isvalid
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: Information: isvalid
 ..... (the same infinite loop message) ............
```

If I remove the console.log, the pre-rendering works, but I suppose the proccess keep on checking the if the button isValid or not.

My package versions

```
"angular2-platform-node": "2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal": "2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal-patch": "0.2.1",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "2.1.0-rc.1",
"aspnet-prerendering": "2.0.3",

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices : 1.1.0;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices : 1.1.0;
```

Comment: I got a similar problem. I have [attr.disabled]="cantLoadMore()" on a <a> tag cantLoadMore() is a method on component. Dont know why there are something call cantLoadMore() repeatly infinite

Comment: I didn't resolve this issue. I stop mixing .net core with angular2

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that when you call a method in the template, it is called every time change detection is run, which happens often. So this is actually not an infinite loop, Angular just calls this method on each change detection.

You can solve this by handling the logic in the component, store it in a variable, and use the variable in the template.